# onCommand syntax error bukkit plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

```
package me.Nitsua.SwearCatcher;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.event.Event;



public class SwearCatcher extends JavaPlugin {
public final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static SwearCatcher plugin;


@Override
public void onDisable() {
    PluginDescriptionFile pdfFile = this.getDescription();
    this.logger.info(pdfFile.getName() + " has been disabled!");
}

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    PluginDescriptionFile pdfFile = this.getDescription();
    this.logger.info(pdfFile.getName() + " Version " + pdfFile.getVersion() + " Has Been Enabled!");
    PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();


    int count = 0;
    String[] id;
    String[] swear;
    String[] change;



    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;


        if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("sc") || commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("swearcatcher")) {
            if (args.length == 0) {
                player.sendMessage("/sc <Swear> <Change>");
                player.sendMessage("/sc list");
                player.sendMessage("/sc remove <number>");
            }

            if (args.length == 1){
                if (args[0] == "list"){
                    for (int i=0; i = count; i++){
                        player.sendMessage(id[i] +swear[i] + change[i]);

                    }
                }
            }

            if (args.length== 2) {
                if (args[0] == "remove" && args[0] != "") {
                    id[args[1]] = 0;
                    swear[args[1]] = 0;
                    change[args[1]] = 0;    
                } 


                if (args[0] != "remove" && args[0] != "list"){
                count = count + 1;
                id[count] = id[count];
                swear[count] = swear[args[1]];
                change[count] = change[args[2]];
                }
            }
        }
        return false;   
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void playerchats(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event){
        event.setCancelled(true);
        chat = event.getMessage();

        for (i = 0, i = count;;) {
            chat = chat.replaceAll(swear[i], change[i]);
        }
        event.setMessage(chat);
    }
}
```

}

```
 //plugin.yml
 name: SwearCatcher
 main: me.Bench3.SwearCatcher.SwearCatcher
 version: 1.0
 description: Pulls swear words from chat, and makes them better to read!
 main: me.Nitsua234.SwearCatcher.SwearCatcher
 author: Nitsua234

  commands:
   sc list:
     description: List all the swear words, their changes, and their id's.
   sc remove <swear id>:
     description: removes a swear from the list.
   sc <swear> <change>:
     description: replaces a swear with something nice.
```

My problems:
1. There are syntax errors riddled through out the line that starts with public Boolean onCommand(
it keeps saying that i should replace certain brackets with (,)s, although I am assured this is false.

2. it wont load, it keeps telling me i have an invalid plugin.yml, which is right below my code. It keeps telling me i have a bad description, although its fine (or i think it is).
3. I'm still trying to experiment with events, so if you have any tips there, that would be greatly appreciated :). Im trying to use the AsyncPlayerChatEvent, and I think I need to implement listener.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `return false;` or `return true;` on the end of each if statement. It doesn't show up in eclipse but it causes problems I believe. That's about as much as I know.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have huge syntax errors in your class file.

1.) Your onCommand boolean is *inside of your onEnable method* Move it outside of your onEnable method.

2.) Your onCommand boolean also returns *false* making it not return at all.

3.) Your syntax in your plugin yml seems off also, try changing it to:

```
 //plugin.yml
name: SwearCatcher
main: me.Bench3.SwearCatcher.SwearCatcher
version: 1.0
description: Pulls swear words from chat, and makes them better to read!
main: me.Nitsua234.SwearCatcher.SwearCatcher
author: Nitsua234
commands:
```

After commands: You have it wrong also, you do not put all your arguments here *JUST* your main command, which in this case is swearcatcher. Change it to:

```
commands:
  swearcatcher:
    description: List all the swear words, their changes, and their id's.
    aliases: [sc]
```

Having the aliases being sc, will make the command also run when they type `/sc`.

4.) As well as your events, yes you need to *implement a Listener*, not only this, but you need to register it. To register put this in your onEnable

```
this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
```

This will register your events.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your plugin.yml problem:

```
commands:
sc:
 description: List all the sc commands.
```

"sc" is your command. The rest are arguments.

And here you can find everything you need in terms of Events and stuff like that:
http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/doxygen/df/d08/namespaceorg_1_1bukkit_1_1event.html

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to list each argument possible for your main command in the `plugin.yml`. It should instead look something like this:

`commands:
  sc:
    description: whatever you want players to see in /help`

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to do:

```
usage: /<command>
```

In your plugin.yml.

Comment: That does not do anything. That is optional to have the usage